# How can I make plugin auto open specify file by internal editor in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I'm writting a plugin, open the abc.txt file, and when I already finish create abc.txt, I want to eclipse auto open this file using a internal editor (example ckeditor). How can I do that?

```
IDE.openEditor(page, input, "org.eclipse.ckeditor");
```

I use this code but it's not work.

Anybody help me?

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't work? Did you get an exception? What is 'input'?

Comment: I get exception org.eclipse.ui.PartInitException: Unable to open editor, unknown editor ID: 'org.eclipse.ckeditor'=> How can I know ID of CKEditor? This plugin I was install from update site   http://kosz.bitbucket.org/eclipse-ckeditor/update-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the id of an editor you look for the `org.eclipse.ui.editors` extension point used to declare the editor in the `plugin.xml` file in the plugin jar.

In this case the editor id is `org.eclipse.ckeditor.editors.CKEditor`